# How do I go from this ["url", "395868"] to this [name: "url", value: "395868"]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm beginning with javascript and I feel like I don't have too much vocabulary to explain my issue. I'm trying to build a chart with d3 and here is the data I need :

```
                      data=[
                        {x: 'A', y: 10},
                        {x: 'B', y: 5},
                        {x: 'C', y: 15}
                      ]/>
```

but right now here is what I have `[['A',10],['B',5],['C',15]]`

So... how do I merge my data and how do I add the "x" and "y" categories name.

Comment: `Array.prototype.map()` is your friend.

Comment: You are mixing arrays and objects in your code...

Comment: @Redu. thanks, I've check some tutorials on this but I couldn't apply it to my exemple. Huntro can you explain me a bit more what you're saying ?

Comment: @SimonBreton `{[ ... ]}` is not valid. Everything inside `{}` must be in the form `key: value`.

Comment: How do you have this `['A',10]['B',5]['C',15]`? Is `[['A',10],['B',5],['C',15]]`what you are trying to mean?

Comment: `data={[{x: 'A', y: 10},{x: 'B', y: 5},{x: 'C', y: 15}]}` isn't a valid statement. You properly wanted an array: `data=[{x: 'A', y: 10},{x: 'B', y: 5},{x: 'C', y: 15}]`

Comment: @SimonBreton Just write any kind of loop that processes the original array, and pushes the desired objects onto the result array. This is a Javascript 101 problem.

Comment: Diego, Huntro, thanks I've updated my code. Is my issue is clearer now ? @Barmar I don't understand nothing about what you say. Can you give me an example ?

Comment: I've tried something like this `var data = [['A',10],['B',5],['C',15]]
dataformat = data.map(function(d,i){
    return {"x":d, "y":i};
});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some ES6 code that transforms the one to the other:

```js
var data = [['A',10],['B',5],['C',15]];

var result = data.map( ([x, y]) => ({ x, y }) );

console.log(result);
```

#### Explanation

`data.map()`: the `map` method will go through each element of `data` (there are 3 elements), and call the function you provide it as argument. That function will thus be called three times, and each time it will be passed the current element as argument.

`(...) => ....` this is the ES6 arrow syntax. It represents a function, but with some different rules. These differences are not relevant in this answer, so I wont go into that.

`[x, y]`: this is the argument given by `map`: it is one of the array elements. Normally you would have just one variable here (or several separated by commas), but here we use a "destructuring assignment": we expect the argument to be an array, and want to assign its elements to variables `x` and `y`. So the first time `x` will have the value `"A"`, and `y` will be `10`, ...etc.

`=>`: the arrow of the arrow function. What follows is the expression that will be returned by the function.

`({ x, y })`: the parentheses are only necessary to avoid confusion with a statement block, which also starts with a brace. The `{ x, y }` is the object to return. Here again we use ES6 syntax which actually interprets this as `{ "x": x, "y": y }`; it's a shortcut notation.

So the `map` method will call the function three times, and each time an object is returned. `map` will put these in a new array, and return that array.

Here is similar code in ES5 syntax:

```js
var data = [['A',10],['B',5],['C',15]];

result = data.map(function(arr) {
    return { x: arr[0], y: arr[1] };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks seems to work. can you give me a little bit more detailed answers on how this work ?

Answer (score 0):

Pure ES3+ solution? Not tested but I believe it works.

```js
var arr  = [['A',10],['B',5],['C',15]],
    data = [];
    
    for (a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
      var obj = {};
      obj.x = arr[a][0];
      obj.y = arr[a][1];
      data[a] = obj;
    }

    console.log(data);
```

Comment: Maybe you should have tested it, because it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

If you use library called Lodash - https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#map

```
_.map([['A',10]['B',5]['C',15]], function(o) { return {x:o[0], y:o[1]}; });
```

**Edit**

If you don't use Lodash in your project, that might be a bit overkill

Comment: You suggest using a library for this kind of problem?

Comment: No I'm not. I guess there should be a simple javascript solution no ?

Comment: There is a bit difference - "Use Lodash" and "If you use Lodash" @Marc

Comment: Still a little far-fetched to suggest a Lodash based solution to a JS beginner.

Comment: @SimonBreton - yes - lodash's `_.map()` is actually natively supported in all browsers (that aren't IE8) in the face of `Array.prototype.map()`. In fact, lodash should delegate to the native implementation, if it finds one